# PHP file upload - files not readable from /tmp/ in production but they are in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, file-permissions, linode

I'm stuck on what probably is a file permissions problem. I've spent 10 hours straight on this and I'm at the point of giving up because I literally have no idea how to fix it. My script works perfectly on localhost as well.

I have the following code as part of a file upload script within a controller in my CodeIgniter application:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$config['upload_path'] = '/tmp/';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload("selected_file");

// Variables used later when resizing an image
$originalPostImageFileUploadPath        = $this->upload->data()['full_path'];
$originalPostImageFileUploadFilePath    = $this->upload->data()['file_path'];
$originalPostImageFileRawName           = $this->upload->data()['raw_name'];
$originalPostImageFileExt               = $this->upload->data()['file_ext'];
$originalPostImageFileUniqId            = uniqid();


print_r($this->upload->data());
echo file_get_contents($originalPostImageFileUploadPath);
```

Here's the output I get when I upload a file:

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => fosters.jpg
    [file_type] => image/jpeg
    [file_path] => /tmp/
    [full_path] => /tmp/fosters.jpg
    [raw_name] => fosters
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => fosters.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 49408
    [is_image] => 1
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  file_get_contents(/private/tmp/fosters.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: ajax/product.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 45</p>
```

As you can see, the script appears to uploading the file correctly but the file_get_contents() fails because it can't find the file.

What I've tried:

Creating a script with the following code to see if the www-data has sufficient permissions:

```
echo (is_writable('/tmp/') ? "yes" : "no");
echo (is_readable('/tmp/') ? "yes" : "no");
```

Both of the above outputs return 'yes' (true)

Changing the chmod of the /tmp/ directory:
`chmod 777 /private/tmp/` (as bad as this is)

Changing `upload_max_filesize` to `128M` (the file is nowhere near this size)

I've even tried running the following command to see if the file gets uploaded to the /tmp/ directory. It seems it does, but it gets removed in an instant (in less than 0.1 seconds).

```
watch --interval=0.1 ls
```

What else can I try? `whoami` returns `www-data`, so am I right in saying something like `chown wwww-data /tmp/` should fix the problem? Help

Answer (score 0):

Usually POSTed file uploads via PHP get sent to a temporary /folder/file and deleted if you don't use the recommended functions, which include: `move_uploaded_file()` for example my POSTed array has:

```
name
size
type
tmp_name
```

I use something like this:

```
$fileName=$_FILES["resume"]["name"];
$fileSize=$_FILES["resume"]["size"];
$fileType=$_FILES["resume"]["type"];
$fileTmpName=$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"];  
$targetFile="/srv/www/uploads/".$fileName;  // Where-ever you want your file to be, you can delete manually later on in the script

/* various checking of size and type etc */

if(!is_uploaded_file($fileTmpName)) {
    echo "Couldn't upload file";
    die(0);
}
if(!move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$targetFile)) {
    echo "Couldn't move file";
    die(0);
}

/* now target file exists and stays put */
```

Comment: this does not answer OP's question. OP is referring to codeigniter.

Comment: yea but it called a php file which is his problem

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason why I haven't used the move_uploaded_file() function is because I'm doing validation checks on the file and uploading to Amazon S3 later on in the script. The problem is that my script doesn't seem to work at all on my production server, and I can't seem to figure out which setting I should change to make it work :(